# Trolling the Russians with deliberately deadly rocket fuel

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to re-find what might be a short story or a real-life account by a well-known science fiction author.  This author was talking to a retired aerospace engineer who spun a tale about a project he worked on to come up with the absolutely most hideous rocket that could be conceived.  The idea was to troll the Russians by letting known Russian spies get a hold of documents describing this design.  The rocket fuel involved the most toxic substances known along with radioactive components.  Russian experimentation with "Devil's Venom" (a real fuel combination) wasn't it.

Comment: The "funny" thing about "Devil's Venom" is that hydrazine, one of the most dangerous substance available, is commonly found in US fighter planes (see 
 https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23417/why-is-hydrazine-used-to-power-the-f-16s-epu ) . As soon as one of them crashes somewhere, the spot become a highly hazardous spot. 
And the US played with chemical and bacteriological weapons, disposing of them below Denver ... just to trigger some big earthquake https://coloradogeologicalsurvey.org/1967/62887-case-study-denver-august-9-1967 
You need no trolling with such adversaries...

Comment: Just as an aside, this is pretty much the McGuffin behind Desmond Bagley's book *The Tightrope Men*. The Brits feed the USSR a plausible lie about a fictional missile defense system, in the hope that it'll tie up their scientists for years to come - except the Russians are a step ahead. Cold War spy stuff ensues.

Comment: @EarlGrey Hydrazine is a very common propellant for rocketry, from ICBM to boosters to orbital manoeuvering systems. Sometimes used with equally toxic oxidizers. Yes, it kills your liver, wear haz,mat suits. ["Command and Control"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_and_Control_(book)), a book by Eric Schlosser, narrates the problems that a hole in a Titan 2 ICBM hydrazine tank caused, eventually blowing up the launch complex and throwing the H bomb into the greens. It's great fun. PBS did a documentary based on that.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This sounds a lot like *[A Tall Tail](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1527829)* by Charles Stross, a short story published in 2012.

The story has the central character attending a rocketry conference in Florida, and getting into conversation with an old-time rocket engineer, who told him about a CIA-funded plan (codename NAIL SPIKE) to get the Soviets to test a really unpleasant rocket fuel. For the oxidiser they would use dioxygen difluoride, FOOF (for an amusing account of FOOF's terrifying properties, read [Derek Lowe's blog](https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/things-i-won-t-work-dioxygen-difluoride)):

> “First, there’s an oxidizing agent that’s even nastier than chlorine
> trifluoride.” Dr Hansen grinned. “It’s called FOOF, dioxygen
> difluoride. You make it by reacting liquid fluorine and liquid oxygen
> in a cryogenic steel reaction vessel under X-ray bombardment...

and for fuel they would use an organic mercury compound: dimethylmercury

> Mercury is nasty stuff, but organic mercury compounds are even nastier, and and dimethylmercury is one
> of the worst. It’s not merely poisonous; it’s about the strongest
> neurotoxin we’ve got. In fact, just about its only use is as a
> reference test for toxicity.

(Indeed, dimethylmercury is so toxic that in the real world a researcher died after a single drop of it fell on her gloved hand. Stross is not exaggerating its effects at all). Having come up with this cocktail, they carefully leaked the recipe to the Soviets:

> So. We leaked the design for the FOOF/dimethylmercury test motor to
> the Soviets, claiming it had an insanely high specific impulse—” the
> measure of a rocket’s efficiency “—and was ideal for anti-shipping
> missiles because the fuel’s extremely dense, so your missile can have
> a smaller frontal cross-section, which is good when you’re pushing
> through dense air at sea level. And we made sure to salt the documents
> with references to a special additive that made it all stable and safe
> to handle.

Searching for the "special additive" led the Soviets to discover red mercury, and then via various twists and turns of plot, firing the rocket motor led to the Chernobyl disaster.

The full story is available from this [website](https://reactormag.com/a-tall-tail/).

Comment: For anyone wanting an excellent and (apparently) mostly true read full of amusing stories like the above, you should read John D. Clark's [Ignition](https://archive.org/details/ignition_201612)

Comment: And as if dimethyl mercury wasn't horrifying enough, the lady who died from a small quantity on her glove died *ten months* after the exposure.

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking at Derek Lowe's article about FOOF, was reminded of the story, but somehow missed finding the story.

Comment: Such a story makes only sense if Soviets are assumed to have absolutely zero knowledge about chemistry, physics and mechanics and are basically cargo cult monkeys. Which they certainly aren't. They had excellent rocket motors. Typical for Charles Stross, he can write a good yarn but his sciency things, though they have all the required technical terms, never work.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer It sort of depends, given that (at least according to Ignition), the US also did experiments with using dimethylmercury and chlorine trifluoride in the past. Fluorizing agents and dimethylmercury are actually fairly potent fuel components, they just have the downside of being incredibly hard to handle and any accidents would be utter disasters. I'm not sure if scientists would consider the existence of a stabilizing additive to be reasonable or not.

Comment: @kenod Clark intended to test with dimethylmercury, but Eastman Kodak refused to supply it. So he moved to plain mercury instead.

Comment: A quote about chlorine trifluoride from John Clark's *Ignition!*, via Derek Lowe's blog article, [Sand Won't Save You This Time](https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/sand-won-t-save-you-time). "It is, of course, extremely toxic, but that's the least of the problem. It is hypergolic with every known fuel, and so rapidly hypergolic that no ignition delay has ever been measured. It is also hypergolic with such things as cloth, wood, and test engineers, not to mention asbestos, sand, and water-with which it reacts explosively".

Comment: Yeah, there are very good reasons they never actually used any of said fuels (mostly not wanting to poison everything within a dozen miles of the flight path, or ignite your entire rocket with an unquenchable fire which poisons everything downwind if the fuel tank's fluoride layer fails even slightly), but they're pretty potent fuels.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez True, but the fact that it was actually considered says a lot. The fact that their first idea was outsourcing manufacturing, and their second idea was dropping it entirely also says a lot.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether the researcher dying due to dimethyl mercury was a part of the story, or reality. Unfortunately it's a real fact: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karen_Wetterhahn#Accident_and_death

Comment: @EvilSnack IIRC, she spent eight months screaming and moaning, and nobody could work out whether any human consciousness remained.

Comment: @nigel222 Reading the [case study](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM199806043382305), it seems like she spent "only" 4 months in a vegetative state before death.